# Knockoutjs - Can I create a foreach binding using a View Model parameter?

Tags: knockout.js

I want to create a sort of table in which I have listed

I'm going to map some MVC Models into Ko ViewModel in this way some models:

```
function User(data) {
    this.userAlias = ko.observable(data.UserAlias);
    this.userFirstName = ko.observable(data.UserFirstName);
    this.userLastName = ko.observable(data.UserLastName);
};

function Day(data) {
    var self = this;

    self.date = ko.observable(data.Date);
    self.dateStr = ko.observable(data.dateStr);
    self.dtDay = ko.observable(data.dtDay);
    self.value = ko.observable(data.Value);

    self.users = ko.observableArray([]);
};
```

Where the `users` value of `Day()` is an Array of `User()`.
How can I build a valid Array an in order to use it as a parameter?

Comment: Where are you getting the `User` data from?

Comment: I retrieve both Day and User data using a `$.getJSON` action.

Comment: Just a tip, take a look at the mapping plugin: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Day view model` would look something like this if you were making an ajax call...

```
function Day(data) {
    var self = this;

    self.date = ko.observable(data.Date);
    self.dateStr = ko.observable(data.dateStr);
    self.dtDay = ko.observable(data.dtDay);
    self.value = ko.observable(data.Value);

    self.users = ko.observableArray([]);

    var users = this.users;

    //get users and push into observable array
    $.getJSON('url', function (json) {
            var mappedData = ko.utils.arrayMap(json, function (u) {
                return new User(u.UserAlias, u.UserFirstName, u.UserLastName);
           });
         users(mappedData);
      });
};
```

Your markup would look something like this...

```
data-bind="foreach: users"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ko.toJSON](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html) as follow:

```
var raw = ko.toJSON(self.users());
```